# Titan Hadoop-Gremlin Configuration Issues

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, titan, gremlin

I am trying to get Titan to work with Tinkerpop 3.0.1 Hadoop-Gremlin, by following the Titan Documentation [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/titan-hadoop-tp3.html). I am basically working with a fresh download of titan-1.0.0-hadoop1, from [this](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Downloads) downloads page.

I pretty much follow the documentation exactly, with the only difference being that I am using an HBase backed graph, rather than the Cassandra graph used in the documentation. I am sure that my 'titan-hbase-cluster.properties' file has no errors and can read/write to/from HBase without any issue.

So, following the Titan documentation, I issue the following commands in the gremlin console:

```
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: aurelius.titan
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/src/titanTest/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/src/titanTest/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
23:17:17 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopGraph  - HADOOP_GREMLIN_LIBS is set to: /usr/src/titanTest/lib
plugin activated: tinkerpop.hadoop
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin> :load data/grateful-dead-titan-schema.groovy
==>true
==>true
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-hbase-cluster.properties')
==>standardtitangraph[cassandrathrift:[127.0.0.1]]
 gremlin> defineGratefulDeadSchema(graph)
==>null
gremlin> graph.close()
==>null
gremlin> hdfs.copyFromLocal('data/grateful-dead.kryo','data/grateful-dead.kryo')
23:22:46 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
==>null
gremlin> graph = GraphFactory.open('conf/hadoop-graph/hadoop-load.properties')
==>hadoopgraph[gryoinputformat->nulloutputformat]
gremlin> blvp = BulkLoaderVertexProgram.build().writeGraph('conf/titan-cassandra.properties').create(graph)
==>BulkLoaderVertexProgram[bulkLoader=IncrementalBulkLoader,vertexIdProperty=bulkLoader.vertex.id,userSuppliedIds=false,keepOriginalIds=true,batchSize=0]
gremlin> graph.compute(SparkGraphComputer).program(blvp).submit().get()
```

After running these commands, I get the following string of warnings and errors

```
23:23:51 WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.process.computer.spark.SparkGraphComputer  - class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.NullOutputFormat does not implement PersistResultGraphAware and thus, persistence options are unknown -- assuming all options are possible
23:23:58 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy  - Snappy native library not loaded
23:23:58 ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor  - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.gryo.GryoRecordReader.seekToHeader(GryoRecordReader.java:82)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.gryo.GryoRecordReader.initialize(GryoRecordReader.java:74)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.gryo.GryoInputFormat.createRecordReader(GryoInputFormat.java:39)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(NewHadoopRDD.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:280)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:280)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
23:23:58 WARN  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.gryo.GryoRecordReader.seekToHeader(GryoRecordReader.java:82)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.gryo.GryoRecordReader.initialize(GryoRecordReader.java:74)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.ioofasdsadsa dsadsadsa dsa dsa dsadsa.gryo.GryoInputFormat.createRecordReader(GryoInputFormat.java:39)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(NewHadoopRDD.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:280)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:280)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

23:23:58 ERROR org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  - Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent fai.java:82)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.gryo.GryoRecordReader.initialize(GryoRecordReader.java:74)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.gryo.GryoInputFormat.createRecordReader(GryoInputFormat.java:39)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(NewHadoopRDD.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:280)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:280)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Also of interest is the "WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable" error given when I copy to hdfs. Does anyone have any sort of suggestion on how to proceed? I am very lost, since I'm just trying to follow the documentation and hitting a road block pretty early on.

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I am getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You got an `EOFException` which means something went wrong with the file that contains your data. As shown in the implementation of [GryoRecordReader](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.0.1-incubating/hadoop-gremlin/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/hadoop/structure/io/gryo/GryoRecordReader.java#L77), the code seems to be fine.

My suggestions is check if your file is fine, readable and contains utf-8 characters.